# Javascript Ldap Error [ConnectionError: url link closed]

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap

Hi i tried authenticating an LDAP connection though the below code. After trying a couple of combinations, this was the best i could come up with.

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({
    url: 'ldap://xxx.org',
    bindDN: ''
});


client.bind('cn=root', 'bindlocal', function(err){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }else {
        console.log('authenticated');
    }
});

client.unbind(function(err){

});
```

But this generated this error code

```
{ [ConnectionError: ldap://xxx.org closed]
  dn: [Getter],
  code: [Getter],
  name: [Getter],
  message: [Getter] }
```

What could i be doing wrong? any tips would be helpful

Comment: Can you access the LDAP system from your computer using a 'normal' client? That would be the first to check, as the error indicates the server doesn't want to talk to you.

Comment: Yes. I can access it though a normal LDAP client.

Comment: In that case I'd guess you can get try and gather some more information by explicitely logging console.log(err.dn), console.log(err.code), console.log(err.name) and console.log(err.message) -- it could be that message contains additional information. Maybe there is a protocol mismatch? Username/password requirement?

Comment: Fixed it! had to append the right port number to the url